# When i need to use hashMap because it is not synchronized

Tags: java, hashmap

> I know  Hashtable is synchronized, whereas HashMap is not.

As per my knowledge synchronization means accessing a object at a time by one thread.

So there is no problem while using Hashtable. But in my project I am using HashMap. I used it 
in many places. Till now I did not get any problem with HashMap.

So when the synchronization concept will come into the picture(i.e using HashMap).

Can I use HashMap in all places where I am using HashTable?

Can I use HashTable in all places where I am using HashMap?

Comment: some one is voted for closing.Can please give me the reason

Comment: You asked a question specifically with regards to the way you are using it in your program and didn't show an example of the program.  How are we supposed to know if what you did in your program is safe or not?  We don't even know if your program is actually multi-threaded.

Comment: Hello sir i asked generally not specifically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So there is no problem while using Hashtable

Not exactly - in some situations, hashtables do require external synchronization (for example while iterating).

> when will the synchronization concept come into the picture (i.e using HashMap)?

If you have a class that holds a HashMap:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Map map = new HashMap();
}
```

and you access `map` from several threads, you might get unexpected behaviour and should use adequate synchronization.

As long as you only access your map from a single thread or it is a local variable within a method, you are fine.

> Can I use HashMap in all places where I am using HashTable?

cf. above: yes if the map is not accessed by several threads.

> Can I use HashTable in all places where I am using HashMap?

Yes always, although it will probably be less efficient performance-wise.

Comment: In my project i used HashMap in many places.Till now i did not get any problem

Comment: @PSR The fact that you did not get any problems does not mean you won't get any in the future.

Comment: here multiple threads means accessing multiple users same method? I am confusing with this

Comment: can u give a simple example for me

Comment: @PSR no it means multiple threads - to be honest it is a fairly complex topic: I suggest you read more about threads and concurrency here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem unless multiple threads are accessing the very same instance *concurrently*. If you are working with multiple threads you might also look at [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).